# How to import the Tensorflow libraries in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda

A very basic question.

I am trying to install tensorflow library in Anaconda python(spyder).

```
import tf.contrib.keras.preprocessing
```

Its is giving me error as `"No module found".` I also tried import tensorflow.contrib.keras.preprocessing

I also tried
`from tf.contrib.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer`.

This also doesnt work

However I verified this in the tensorflow website, and it is present. 
The link to the library is https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/keras/preprocessing.

I tried to pip and conda install. But that also throwing out error.

From anaconda prompt i typed this:

```
activate tensorflow 
pip install tf.contrib.keras.preprocessing
conda install tf.contrib.keras.preprocessing
```

Is there anything i miss out, Please correct me.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Show your install commands.

Comment: @LiamHealy - I am using windows 7

Comment: @MadPhysicist - import tf.contrib.keras.preprocess  and import tensorflow.contrib.keras.preprocessing. Error message that i got is 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named  tensorflow.contrib.keras.preprocessing'

Comment: Install, not import. You mention running pip and conda but don't show actual commands.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - Sorry. I refined the question as per your suggesition.

Comment: @DoubtDhanabalu the two install command are wrong as explained in my answer. You cannot use `tf` but have to write tensorflow

Comment: @Y0da - I used both tensorflow and tf. However if you see the link that i have given above, it has been give has tf. only. I dont know what mistake i am doing.

Comment: @DoubtDhanabalu it just for simplicity. Go read the code you will see that it is an alias of tensorflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are doing it wrong as `tf` is not the name of the `tensorflow` module but an alias in the tutorials.

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

Thus try this:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
```

From your comments it seems that the module might not be installed so you can check in the list of installed packages:

```
conda list
```

If not present, install it with `pip`. Follow the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows).

Comment: @DoubtDhanabalu If only importing tensorflow does not work it means that you have not installed it. Or that you are not in the good environment in conda. Do `conda list` to see if you are in the correct env and if you are do `conda list` to check installation and if not do `conda install tensorflow`

Comment: I imported the other libraries in tensorflow. But this something it is not working for me. I have tensorflow installed and working for few days.

Comment: Your solution has worked for me. I was inititally doing some mistake which prevented me from execution. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it through Anaconda rather than pip (`pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow`):

1. Create a conda environment called `tensorflow`: `C:> conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5`
2. Activate the environment: `C:> activate tensorflow`
3. Install tensorflow into your environment: `(tensorflow)C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl` (CPU) or `(tensorflow)C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl` (GPU)

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question about import

Comment: He should be able to do what he was after this

Comment: @LiamHealy - Thanks for the response. I was doing this only. I updated the question. Sorry for the inconvenience caused to you.